# Unable to upload folder file onto Google Drive in .Net MVC using webAPI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I am working on **.Net MVC WebAPI** .I have fetch the data from my local database in visual studio and stored into csv file at my local machine in C drive. Now I want to upload to my  google drive what should i do next?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Get")]
public void ExportcontentCSV()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    var get = db.Clients.ToList();

    sb.AppendFormat("{0},{1},{2},{3}",
        "id", "FirstName", "LastName", "DOB");
    sb.Append("\r\n");

    foreach (var all in get)
    {

        sb.AppendFormat(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\"",
            all.id, all.FirstName, all.LastName, all.DOB));
        sb.Append("\r\n");
    }
    StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(@"C:\New folder\pqr.csv");

    File.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

    File.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  Google Drive API , more details [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk)